# Search a string beginning with a prefix in Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: string, google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I want to search all entities whose name starts with a specific string, is this possible in Datastore?

I've tried this:

```
q = datastore.NewQuery("Places").Filter("Name > ", "a")
```

But it doesn't work.

If this is not possible, what alternative solution can you suggest to me? BigQuery? BigTable or other services on App Engine?

Comment: Remove the trailing space: `"Name > "` and try again.

Comment: the trailling space ? it is the same thing as you no?

Comment: Change it to: `"Name >"`.  Also, how do you know it isn't working?  >a means all letters except a.  Is that what you are getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something that is possible, but with a combination of 2 inequality filters.

Let's say you want to list `Places` that have the `"li"` prefix. This can be described with a query that lists `Places` that are greater than (or equal to) `"li"` **and** less than a prefix that is the next string after `"li"` in lexicographical order: `"lj"`.

This is how the GQL looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM Places WHERE Name > 'li' AND Name < 'lj'
```

Coded in Go it looks like this:

```
q = datastore.NewQuery("Places").Filter("Name >", "li").Filter("Name <", "lj")
```

This will list `Places` where name is for example:

```
liam
lisotto
lizst
```

But will exclude names like:

```
abc
ljoi
lj
qwerty
```

One thing to note: small and capital letters are different in lexicographical order, so for example `"List"` is less than `"li"` (even though `"list"` is greater than `"li"`)!

Comment: @Fantasim If an answer works and solves your problem, you should accpet it. You have many questions but you haven't accepted a single answer. There's a gray "tick"  below the votes of the answer, you can accept it by clicking on that. Hovering the mouse over that will display a text: _"Click to accept this answer..."_

Comment: Could you precise in your answer why this solution doesn't work with an order filter ?

Comment: @Fantasim By "order filter" you mean a simple `.Filter("Name >", "li")`? Because this single filter will also accept `"ljoi"` for example, which does not have a `"li"` prefix. The 2nd filter `.Filter("Name <", "lj")` is needed to exclude everything whose prefix is "beyond" `"li"`.

Comment: q = datastore.NewQuery("Places").Filter("Name >", "sorb").Filter("Name <", "sorc").Offset(0).Limit(10).Order("-PostNb") . If i put Order("-PostNb") query get me 0 entitie

Comment: @Fantasim Most likely because you don't have the appropriate index. Every search / filter operates on an index. Filtering by `Name` requires the `Name` property to be indexed. If you also want the results to be ordered by `PostNb`, you need an index that includes both. Also: _"...if a query specifies inequality filters on a property and sort orders on other properties, the property used in the inequality filters must be ordered before the other properties."_ ([source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/queries#sort_orders))