# Alternative way of like operator to search on column in google cloud datastore

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Go lang with datastore as a database, I have to apply search on the UI table by the backend (i.e BY API). So  I went through the documentation and found there is no LIKE OPERATOR is supported in datastore. I also search with regex but this is also not supported.

Still, I want to do it, Please assist with me these guys, I am really needy

```
// Here ParcelKind is the table name

var name string

name ="s"

q:= datastore.NewQuery(ParcelKind).Filter("Name", name%)
```

Comment: Prefix searches are possible, see [Search a string beginning with a prefix in Google App Engine Datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279779/search-a-string-beginning-with-a-prefix-in-google-app-engine-datastore/39280135#39280135). General `like` queries are not.

Answer (score 0):

Try This
q:= datastore.NewQuery(ParcelKind).Filter("Name >=", name%)

Comment: We can't use '%' in the query. Though I have achieved this with Filter("Name >=", name) but it searches from the start of the string I Want to search through entire string.
The second thing is that is there any alternative way to use the "OR" operator in a query.